# Invariants of solutions in permutation groups and Rubik's Cubes

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, permutations

I would like to say beforehand that I am not very informed at all in this area of mathematics, but I do take interest in it.

For a couple of months now I have been thinking about a possibility, and in that time I haven't made any more progress. I thought of a new mathematical object based on the sequences of moves on a Rubik's Cube: $F$,$B$,$L$,$R$,$U$,$D$ and their inverses, which correspond to face turns. I shall call this new object a solution, for lack of a better term. A solution can be defined by a sequence of moves and all of the other sequences that are achievable by repeatedly applying an operation to the sequence of moves. That operation, which preserves the action of the sequence of moves, is to replace any sub-sequence $R$ of the sequence with $R^{1-p(R)}$ or equivalently $(R^{-1})^{p(R)-1}$ where $p(R)$ denotes the order of the subgroup generated by $R$. That is, any sequences in which one can get to the other using only this operation are equivalent solutions according to my definition.

Now my idea is to find an invariant for solutions, or process which takes a solution and gives an output independent of the solution's representation. This is the part I am stuck on, but the idea seems so natural to me that I am convinced that such an invariant exists. With an invariant, I could prove that it is impossible to "simplify" a given sequence of moves to another if the invariants of the two are different. If a useful invariant were found, it may allow me to prove that a certain class of algorithms for solving the Rubik's Cube can never be God's algorithm since they may not be able to produce all of the possible invariants for perfect solutions to all of the positions.

Has there been a lot of research on this topic? Has such an invariant been found? Where can I learn more about this topic so I can try to make some progress with the problem of finding God's algorithm?

Perhaps this idea could be generalized to other games, or permutation groups in general with different generating permutations.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are assuming that each move sequence has a unique invariant, but, if I am understanding your definition of invariant, there is more than one for most if not all move sequences.  So this will not help.

Comment: By invariant I mean anything that takes my "solution" and gives a value that is the same for any equivalent solution. I don't intend for every solution to have a unique invariant, but simply to be able to use it to distinguish some solutions and perhaps shed light on some algorithms for solving the cube.